# How to add css to a data-field attribute?

Tags: css

I have the following code and i would like to add a css specific css code (`width:200px;`) to the `data-field="data2"` elements:

```
<th data-field="data1" class="header">
<th data-field="data2" class="header">
<th data-field="data3" class="header">
<th data-field="data4" class="header">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
[data-field="data2"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th data-field="data1" class="header">yo</th>
  <th data-field="data2" class="header">yo</th>
  <th data-field="data3" class="header">yo</th>
  <th data-field="data4" class="header">yo</th>
</table>
```

Comment: you are missing double quote after `data2`

Answer (score 1):

Attributes different from class and id can be accessed in css with square brackets syntax, in the `[nameOfField="value"]` form, so in your example:

```
[data-field="data2"] {
  width:200px;
}
```

You can find more information about css atribute selectors here:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) to select elements with specified attribute and value:

```
th[data-field="data2"] {
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

```
th[data-field="data2"]  { 
   width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```css
table th[data-field="data2"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th data-field="data1" class="header">1</th>
  <th data-field="data2" class="header">2</th>
  <th data-field="data3" class="header">3</th>
  <th data-field="data4" class="header">4</th>
</table>
```